# Cannot apply filter on whole columns in Excel of exported DevExpress grid

Tags: excel, gridview, devexpress

I've exported a DevExpress grid in Excel.  I want to be able to apply Excel filters on exported Excel sheet.  Right now, the Excel export only allows me to apply filters on values between dark grey rows (rows that already have sums in them).  See pics.
(Could this be because of the cell merge that happened in the formatting?)
I'm using a the following method to export:

```
Using link As New PrintableComponentLink(New PrintingSystem())

                Dim options As New XlsxExportOptionsEx
                options.ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.DataAware
                options.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Value 'Should set to Value to be able to have the numbers displayed as numbers instead of text.
                options.AllowCellMerge = DefaultBoolean.False

                link.Component = gcInvisibleDetail
                link.CreateDocument(link.PrintingSystem)
                link.ExportToXlsx(tbRepertoire.Text & "\Charges.xlsx", options)

End Using
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter Cannot be apply to whole columns because there is a small indents on the top and at the bottom within the group footer row 7,9,15 and 17 in your example, empty rows in Excel emulate these indents.

These rows are added to support the WYSIWYG principe of the grid export.

You can review this topic:

[Problem with XtraGrid Group Footer rending when exporting to excel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T108862)

Comment: Your link pointed me in the right direction.  Ended up just using the following line that fixed all my problems:  `gridview.ExportToXlsx(file)`
Thanks!